# How to print a pandas dataframe after applying the style properties Object <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have tried using display method from IPython
I want to print with **no indexes** and **center align** the values in all columns. I am not using Jupyter notebook; I'm using pyCharm IDE.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.display import display


data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 
         'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).hide_index()
display(df)
```

The output I got is this ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqs1r.png)):

```
**<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x0000029ED0913550>**
```

I want to do it in .py file.
Also is there any way I can print dataframes of pandas in Sciview or Database tool windows that are available in pyCharm?
[SciView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA52b.png)

Comment: You cannot use the Styler or `display` outside of a dynamic HTML environment like Jupyter notebook/IPython.

Comment: Is there any other way to print without indexes and center aligned? or any one of those

Comment: Something like `print(df.to_string(index=False, justify='center'))` or with `tabulate` as `print(df.to_markdown(index=False, tablefmt='plain', colalign=df.columns.map(lambda _: 'center')))`

Comment: You can also use `df.to_html` or `df.to_excel` not only Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to change the bottom portion of my code (when I export the data to excel) to the following:

```
# Append the difference to an existing Excel File
with pd.ExcelWriter('OldData.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    difference.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="1-25-2023")
    print(difference)
```

Comment: This answer is misleading: the OP's question was not about exporting `to_excel()`, it was about displaying the dataframe inside pyCharm IDE windows (not jupyter). Your use-cases are different!